# getView's DialogFragment returning null on onDismiss

Tags: android, view, dialogfragment

I have a custom dialog derived from DialogFragment.

When the user click in the OK button I need  to save the information that is on the screen.

So I made my PositiveButton calls dismiss and I implemented the method onDismiss to save the data.

In the onDismiss method I need do get the data from the editView that is on the Dialog.
I'm using getView().findViewByID to get the editView, but the method GetView() returns null.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_signin, null))
           .setPositiveButton(R.string.signin, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   LoginDialogFragment.this.getDialog().dismiss();
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   LoginDialogFragment.this.getDialog().cancel();
               }
           });      
    return builder.create();
}

@override
public void onDismiss(){
    EditView view = (EditView)getView().findViewByID(R.id.edit);
}
```

I know I can save the view inflated in the OnCreateDialog as a attribute, but that doesn't seems right to me.

How is the right way to get the view from the screen in the onDismiss?

Ps: the place where I work don't allow me to post my code, so I took a code from google and I changed it to be as close as possible of my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Old but gold. This one allows to have bigger control over whole fragment (for example when implementing seekBar or using ButterKnife). Enough said:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_signin, null);
    // do your stuff with views here

    builder.setView(view)
       .setPositiveButton(R.string.signin, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               LoginDialogFragment.this.getDialog().dismiss();
           }
       })
       .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               LoginDialogFragment.this.getDialog().cancel();
           }
       });      
    return builder.create();
}
```

> I know I can save the view inflated in the OnCreateDialog as a attribute, but that doesn't seems right to me.

Yeah, that's the one. It looks right though, especially when implementing things like seekBar and while using libraries like ButterKnife.

Comment: After two years, I do this way too :)

Comment: The wording of this answer is very ambiguous. Instead of saying "Yeah, that's the one. It looks right though", why not say "This is the right way to do it"? Assuming that that is what you are saying, I am still not totally sure.

Comment: Not enough said, in my opinion. I'm also struggling to see what this answer is offering - in terms of both code and explanation.

Comment: One thing that might be worth adding is that it might be worth setting `mView` to null in `onDestroy()` as maybe you could get a memory leak otherwise(??).

Comment: @ban-geoengineering
Yes, but only if You use global variable. Example above has local View variable.

Answer (score 3):

The way that I did my login `DialogFragment` was by using a callback method to the fragment's parent activity like such:

```
builder.setPositiveButton("Login", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                EditText username = (EditText) getDialog().findViewById(R.id.username);
                EditText password = (EditText) getDialog().findViewById(R.id.password);                 

                un = username.getText().toString();
                pw = password.getText().toString();

                    if (un.equals("") || pw.equals("")) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Username or Password field was empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //Don't login & do something (I made a recursive callback to the fragment that created the dialog)
                    }
                    else if (!un.equals("username") || !pw.equals("password")) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Username or Password was incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //Don't login & do something (I made a recursive callback to the fragment that created the dialog)
                    }
                    else if (un.equals("username") && pw.equals("password")) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You have logged in successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        mLogin.Login();
                    }
```

Then the callback method `Login()` will create the next fragment that is needed.

The fragment that will create your login dialog will have the following code within its callback method:

```
LoginDialog login = new LoginDialog();
login.show(getFragmentManager(), "LOGIN");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it safe to cast the return of getDialog() to my Dialog class?

Comment: I'm unsure of what you mean by that? You shouldn't need to cast...?

Comment: The method getDialog returns a object of type Dialog. My dialog extends from DialogFragment.

Can I do the following:
MyDialog dlg = (MyDialog)getDialog();?

Comment: Oh, to create the dialog initially in the fragment parent activity?

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to do that. Now where it says `LoginDialog` that is the name of the java class file that contains your `DialogFragment`.